# visiting a heap memory allocated in another thread throws nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, gradle

[Java - Android] visiting a heap memory allocated in another thread throws nullpointerexception

Here is my code.
loginResult is allocated in a thread doing post request, which callbacks and finally invoked the method afterPassportLoginSuccess() as one of parameters;

[image]

Android Studio: 2021.2.1
Gradle: 6.1.1 (3.6.4)
Source: JAVA_1_8
Target: JAVA_1_8

[Works good]

Android Studio: 2021.3.1
Gradle: 7.2 (7.0.2) (Using jdk 11)
Source: JAVA_1_8
Target: JAVA_1_8

[Works bad: NullPointerExceptions throws].

I dont understand why. loginResult is a heap memory can be visited by any thread.

Any explanation helps me. Thanks.

Comment: loginResult is passing in as an object reference by value in line 39. You set a breakpoint in line 40 and the object reference is still not null there. However, at the moment you are pausing there, another thread may access the same object reference and set it to null.

Comment: so I would like to ask, after the loginResult passes into the method, Is there another thread or process continue to work on this reference and ultimately set it to null?

Comment: or the simplest way to test/fix is to make a "deep copy" of loginResult before passing into the method call. Though convenient way usually is not the best solution since it hides the actual problem, which I guess concurrent access the data object.

Comment: There will be no other thread causing loginResult released. Actually loginResult is just allocated before the method invoked. @AndroidNewbieA